# Class 'App\Rate' not found in the server

Tags: model-view-controller, laravel-5, cpanel

I made a project in laravel. it has got a module that shows some rates picking them from the database. the model connecting with the database table rates is Rate.. The project works well on local host but while put on a server i get this message
 `FatalThrowableError in RateController.php line 33: 
 Class 'App\Rate' not found` 
.. any idea whats the cause and how to fix it

Comment: did you try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: have you namespace your Model correctly? What is your server? Ubuntu, centos ? Which one is it?

Comment: hello the problem is solved.. The name space was the culprit.. rate must be in small case but i wrote it in title case.. but you know the same thing worked in localhost though rate was defined in title case..